# OpenSSL + CAPI: Can find CA cert in Windows cert store, won't validate server cert using it

Tags: openssl

I'm attempting to use the CAPI engine with OpenSSL to make use of the Windows certificate store when connecting to an MQTT broker, but am having an issue where it doesn't seem to use the CA cert from the store.

(This being for MQTT is mentioned as context, but MQTT itself isn't involved in the issue.)

I've fallen back to using openssl.exe to test to eliminate issues in my own code. I'm using the pre-compiled v1.1.1a binaries from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), as listed on the OpenSSL wiki.

It can find the CA cert in the Windows cert store via

```
openssl engine capi -t -post store_name:ROOT -post list_options:8 -post lookup_cert:mqtt
```

but it doesn't seem to use it to validate the server cert when connecting to my broker using

```
openssl s_client -connect 192.168.56.101:8883 -showcerts -engine capi
```

(I added the CA cert to my personal store for this test as I can't find a way to pass commands to the CAPI engine when using s_client and the personal store is the default.)

The client connection says

```
engine "capi" set.
```

and lists the correct certificates sent by the server (I can match the details of the root one against the one in the store), but gives me

```
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

which I take to mean the root cert couldn't be found in the store and therefore the server and CA cert provided by the server are untrusted and the root cert of the chain is therefore considered both self-signed and untrusted.

I've established that the certs are valid by performing a successful connection (with OpenSSL but without CAPI) in my own client application when directly providing the CA cert file.

My questions are therefore:

- To make testing easier, is there a way to pass engine commands to s_client?
- Are there issues with the CAPI engine validating certificates? My searching to date indicates that it's meant to work.
- Is there something I might have missed in my setup?

Comment: Have you made any progress? I am stuck here too.

Comment: @Michael-O Unfortunately I had limited time and using the Windows store wasn't a hard requirement so I ended up loading the certificates from disk instead.

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11417